# What does error TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable mean?

Tags: python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

urls = ['http://www.soku.com/search_playlist/q_python_orderby_1_limitdate_0?site=14&page={}&spm=a2h0k.8191403.0.00'.format(str(i)) for i in range(1,30,1)]

def UUrl(urls):

    def Url(url):
        single_urls = []
        time.sleep(1)
        wb_data = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(wb_data.text,'lxml')
        for single_urls  in soup.find_all(class_ = "album_tit"):
            single_url = (single_urls.a.get('href'))
            return single_url
            # print(single_url)

    for url in urls:
        Url(url)

def get_url_title(urls,data = None):
    urlsss = UUrl(urls)
    for surl in urlsss:
        wb_data = requests.get(surl)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(wb_data.text,'lxml')
        urlss = soup.find_all(class_="title short-title")
        titles = soup.find_all(class_="title short-title")

        for t_url,title in zip(urlss,titles):
            data = {
                 'title':title.get_text(),
                 'url': (t_url.a.get('href'))
            }
            print(data)

get_url_title(urls)
```

Answer (score 1):

It means you are iterating over a null value. The soup.findall function might be returning no results. If that happened the function is returning nonetype, kind of like a null for python. Then you are trying to do a for loop over something that doesnt exist. There are a couple areas in your code that could be throwing this error, but basically it just means that the variable after the expression IN in your for loop has no value. You can do a.   if soup.find_all(class_ = "album_tit") is NoneType: print("find all function not returning a value")